# Wordpress регистрация

Tags: wordpress

Пишу сайт на wordpress. Возникла необходимость сделать регистрацию новых пользователей. Сделал через шорткоды `[bbp-login]` `[bbp-register]`. Возникло два вопроса.

1. При регистрации нет возможности указать пароль, и на почту пароль тоже не приходит. Как задать этот пароль?
2. Авторизация проходит через wp-login т.е. получается создаются пользователи грубо говоря в той же группе что и админ вордпресса - безопасно ли это?

Можно ли как нибудь сделать по-другому?

Comment: В админке смог сгенерировать пароль для пользователя. Получается для каждого пользователя необходимо админу все пароли писать? Данные пользователи имеют доступ к dashbroad вордпресса.

Comment: Т.е. шорткоды `[bbp-login]` `[bbp-register]` дают не только доступ к форуму но и к небольшой части самого вордпресса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вы установили bbPress. Это не совсем сайт, это форум. Если вы установили bbPress только для того, что бы наладить регистрацию, то это того не стоит. Есть куча отличных и более лёгких плагинов для этого. Жду ответа...

1.При регистрации нет возможности указать пароль, и на почту пароль тоже не приходит. Как задать этот пароль? - Есть куча плагинов для вордпресс, которые помогут Вам расширить нужный функционал. У самого есть блог с bbpress и там я установил хороший плагин Lockdown WP Admin, там даже есть настройки, которые блокируют при попытке взлома, что уже не раз пытались.

2.Авторизация проходит через wp-login т.е. получается создаются пользователи грубо говоря в той же группе что и админ вордпресса - безопасно ли это? - это вордпресс, откуда бы не проходила регистрация, пользователи будут в группе что и админ, и да, это безопасно.

Comment: Вы не правильно меня поняли. Сделал сайт и пытаюсь сделать для него форум. Однако bbpres вроде как работает через админку wordpress. Можно ли как нибудь разделить, что бы у bbpress была своя админка.

Comment: Я изменил ответ. Смотрите выше.